# How to make curved arrows

Tags: pgfplots, plot, tkz-graph

I am a math teacher and I still have a hard time getting started with Latex, but I would like to know if someone could help me on how to generate the following example. Researching on the internet I found that I can use PSTricks for the curved lines but I still don't understand how to make the continuous and dotted lines, as well as putting the whole example in a box, since I have always had the problem with the dimensions of the boxes where I put the examples.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution consists in creating empty nodes with an offset in the denominators of the fractions, and connecting them with the `\ncarc` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{sansmath} 

\begin{document}

\sansmath
{\[ \frac{3}{\pnode[0.5ex, -0.5ex]{a}5} + \frac{1}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{b}10} = \frac{6}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{c}10} + \frac{1}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{d}10} = \frac{7}{10}%\
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, arcangle=-40, dash=3pt 2pt}
\ncarc{a}{c}\ncarc[linestyle=dashed]{b}{d}\]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but when I copy the codes in overleaf I get the annoying "undefined control sequence", could you please explain to me why? @Bernard

Comment: @OscarR: What is this undefined control sequence?

Comment: @OscarR are you compiling with pdflatex? That won't work, pstricks needs latex +dvips.

Comment: Or simply xelatex.